# Alternatives to hamburger menus for switching the user context (e.g. active project in a project management app)?

Tags: mobile, navigation, ios

Context: a mobile app for project management where the user at any given time has one active project. Think Slack/Discord/GitHub. Each project has some per-project navigation, in the form of a top tab bar with tasks, people, reports, and other list of items that belong to the project.

The question is how to design a switcher for the active project. On Android I would use a hamburger menu with a drawer listing the projects. On iOS this is discouraged. What are other good alternatives to switch the user's context? A bottom bar is good for switching between "functionality" (e.g. feed, messaging).

Comment: Can you describe why you agree with following the guidelines for iOS and do not want implement the menu there? This might help getting more focused and less opinionated answers.

Comment: Sure. My I want the use to pick one out of 10-100s projects, so a bottom bar doesn't really worth, both conceptually (we're not switching experiences but which top-level item in one experience we want to work with) and scaling wise (the bottom bar only has up to 5 or so items).

Comment: _Why_ is it discouraged in iOS? Perhaps if you explore the rationale for the guideline you can come up with a solution.

Answer (score 3):

To some extent, it depends on how frequently your users would switch projects.

If **frequent**, why not place the switcher in the bottom navigation? Some examples on iOS:

##### Trello

(You can switch account from Account menu)

[image]

##### Reddit

(Communities)

[image]

##### Whatsapp

(Communities)

[image]

---

If **infrequent**, an idea could be to use a top-right menu. The best example are Google's apps, where you can switch accounts from the top-right profile menu:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'd say switching is relatively infrequent. Most of the time the users "home" screen (i.e. first screen) should be that of the current active project, such that that project's tasks are up front and center. The top right menu is what I do on Android but that's discouraged on iOS from what I can tell (it's similar to a hamburger menu, in that it's hidden).